# Stripe PaymentElement and clientSecret

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm a bit confused about the correct way to implement Stripe PaymentElement in a React app.

On one hand, [Stripe suggests](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-provider)  to

> Render an Elements provider at the root of your React app so that it
> is available everywhere you need it

Following is their example:

```
import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

// Make sure to call `loadStripe` outside of a component’s render to avoid
// recreating the `Stripe` object on every render.
const stripePromise = loadStripe(

'pk_test_...'
);

export default function App() {
  const options = {
    // passing the client secret obtained from the server
    clientSecret: '{{CLIENT_SECRET}}',
  };

  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
      <CheckoutForm />
    </Elements>
  );
};
```

What I find confusing already at this point is that client secret is passed at the root of the React app, meaning we're creating a client secret without any client interaction (?). I thought that client secret should be created once a customer wants to pay for something or add a payment method...

On the other hand, Stripe also suggests using PaymentElement for automatically handling different payment methods.

While I have found examples with CardElement where client secret is indeed passed later, upon some customer action (such as adding a payment method for example) I cannot seem to find corresponding example with PaymentElement.

Is there a way to pass client secret to PaymentElement directly without passing it to Elements wrapper? I've tried passing options object as a prop directly to PaymentElement with no success.

Otherwise, what are the downsides of wrapping a single component of an app dedicated to user payment in Elements provider?

How should one go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup like this
`<Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{ mode: 'setup', currency: 'usd' }}>` and it won't be necessary to initialize your app with a client secret. When you want to change the mode (e.g. from 'setup' to 'payment') , you just need to use the useElements hook provided by stripe and can update accordingly.

Hope this helps.

> Otherwise, what are the downsides of wrapping a single component of an app dedicated to user payment in Elements provider?

There is no downside, only that if you wrap it on root, it will be more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, yes the `client_secret` is required before rendering the Payment Element. Your options for the time being are:

- to move your Elements initialization later when you know the payment
  details (ie, on a checkout page  after any card edits and
  shipping/tax are already set/known)
- consider updating the Payment Intent once details change and load those changes with `fetchUpdates` ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/fetch_updates))
- Look at possible beta-feature paths such as [adding server-side logic before final confirmation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/run-custom-actions-before-confirmation)